# Como poner una List<> en un listbox? c#

Tags: c#, lista, listbox

Necesito que una lista de clase de numeros enteros aparezca en una listbox. He tratado de hacerlo pero al parecer estoy haciendo algo mal. Necesito ayuda.

```
//Clase CNumero
namespace Practica
{
    public class CNumero 
    {
        public int numero;

    }}
```

```
//Clase CLista
namespace Practica
{
    public class CLista
    {

        public List<CNumero> Lista_numeros { get; set; }
        public CLista()
        {

            if (Lista_numeros == null)
                Lista_numeros = new List<CNumero>();

        }
        public void IngresarNumero(CNumero numero)
        {

            Lista_numeros.Add(numero);
        }}}
```

Formulario:

```
 private void ButtonAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CNumero cifra = new CNumero();
            cifra.numero = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumero.Text);
            objLista.IngresarNumero(cifra);
            listbox.Items.Add(objLista.Lista_numeros);}
```

Cuando trato de compilar el programa en vez de que me devuelva los números me devulve (Colección)

Toda respuesta es bievenida, estaré agradecido si me pudiesen ayudar.

Comment: Intenta con listbox.DataSourse=objLista; ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuand usas el `Items.Add()` estas asignando `Lista_numeros` que es del tipo `List<CNumero>`, si quires hacer de esta forma deberias iterar la lista

```
foreach(var item in objLista.Lista_numeros)
{
   listbox.Items.Add(item.numero);
}
```

Pero como tienes una lista tambien podrias asignar el `DataSource` para lo cual primero define una propiedad

```
 public class CNumero 
 {
    public int numero {get;set;};
 }
```

Entonces despues indicas las propiedades

```
listbox.DisplayMember = "numero";
listbox.ValueMember = "numero";

listbox.DataSource = objLista.Lista_numeros;
```

debes indicar que propiedad representa el `value` y el  `display` de la lista

[ListControl.DisplayMember Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=netframework-4.8)

[ListControl.ValueMember Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=netframework-4.8)

Puedes usar el `SelectedValue` para tomar el nro seleccionado por el usuario